# Django FileField uploads stored on filesystem with different filename

Tags: django, django-admin

HIn Django, when uploading a file with spaces, and brackets, it's stored in the file system with a different filename.

For example, when uploading the file 'lo go (1).jpg' via the admin interface, it's stored on the filesystem as 'lo__go_1.jpg'.

How can I know what the file will be called at upload time? I can't seem to find the source code that replaces the characters.

Comment: Strange ..  ! I don't have issue with `ImageField`

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer to my question.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L310
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/storage.py#L58
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/text.py#L234